# How to sort the Github User API alphabetically

Tags: api, sorting, github-api

I want to use the github API sorted by user name

I have read the github api documentation but I can't find the answer

My Api

```
https://api.github.com/users?since=135
```

```
search?o=desc&q=john&s=name&type=Users
```

I want to sort the search user API by order name by ASC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs, sorting by name does not seem possible.

`GET /users` [lists all users](https://developer.github.com/v3/users/#get-all-users) in the order that they signed up. This end-point does not offer `sort`, only `since` for pagination.

`GET /search/users` [allows sort](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-users) by the number of followers, or repositories, or when the person joined. But not by `login`.

You may have to fetch the data and then sort it at your end.

FWIW, neither of these endpoints will send the `name` of the user. You need to use the single-user endpoint `GET /users/:username` for that.